# Java ( arrays ) insert,find,delete

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

That code is working if I took off the delete part, but when it exists, the `if(a[i]==searchKey)` in that part shows me an error : `incompatible types; int cannot be inverted to boolean`, so idk what is the problem?

```
          int []a={77,99,44,55,22,88,11,0,66,33};
          int i;
          int searchKey;
          int nElems=10;

          for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
                System.out.println("");
          // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

          searchKey=66;
          for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

                if(a[i]==searchKey)
                    break;
                if(i==nElems)
                    System.out.println("Can't find "+searchKey);
                else
                    System.out.println("Found "+searchKey);
           //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                // DELETE PART !
                searchKey=55;
           for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

                if(a[i]=searchKey)
                break;
                for(int j=i;j<nElems;j++)
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                nElems--;

            for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
                System.out.println("");
```

Comment: It should be `if(a[i] == searchKey)` with `==` and not just `=`.

Answer (score 2):

`if(a[i]=searchKey)` you are **assigning** `a[i]` with the value of `searchKey`, which returns the value of `searchKey` in the evaluation instead of a `boolean`.

Use `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if(a[i]=searchKey)` with `if(a[i]==searchKey)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int []a={77,99,44,55,22,88,11,0,66,33};
int i;
int searchKey;
int nElems=10;

for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

      System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
      System.out.println("");
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

searchKey=66;
for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

      if(a[i]==searchKey)
          break;
      if(i==nElems)
          System.out.println("Can't find "+searchKey);
      else
          System.out.println("Found "+searchKey);
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      // DELETE PART !
      searchKey=55;
 for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)
     // replace assignment operator (=) with realational operator (==)
      if(a[i]==searchKey)
      break;
    //if this runs for 9th time then the index will 10 (j+1=10) so it will through an exception 
    for(int j=i;j<nElems-1;j++)
      a[j]=a[j+1];
      nElems--;

  for(i=0;i<nElems;i++)

      System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
      System.out.println("");
```

two changes were made and it is mentioned in comment line